# ReferenceError: jade is not defined

Tags: node.js, session, express, pug

I've been trying to make a website using express and jade. I have made several pages and routes, and it has worked fine up until now. I keep getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: jade is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> ([...]project/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:165:30), <anonymous>:2:1)
    at Object.exports.render ([...]project/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:211:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile ([...]project/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:247:18)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] ([...]project/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:232:21)
    at View.render ([...]project/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render ([...]project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:506:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/media/ruben/5CCAD622CAD5F7EA/Users/ruben/Google Drev/developer/workspace/kwasi/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:759:7)
    at exports.home ([...]project/routes/cases.js:7:7)
    at callbacks ([...]project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at clientChosen ([...]project/app.js:81:5)
```

When I clear my cache and cookies, I can go to all of my pages, but whenever I log in, that is, set a session variable with the logged in user, I get the above error.

I'm not sure what other information I can include. The line in cases.js that the stack trace is referencing is simply

```
res.render("home.jade", {})
```

EDIT:

In my app.js I specify jade as the rendering engine with the following:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set("views", __dirname + "/views"); // Set the views folder
  app.set("view engine", "jade"); // Set the rendering engine
  ...
```

and my view looks like this:

```
extend layout

block title
  title Forside - #{company}

block content
  h3 Sager

  - for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
    .casethumb
      p #{cases[i].label}
  - }
```

EDIT 2:
Right. What I've been able to determine is that it may have something to do with my custom middleware. I have these two functions

```
// Makes sure that the user is logged in
loggedIn = function(req, res, next){
  if (req.session.user) {
    next()
  }
  else {
    if (req.url != "/login") {
      req.flash('info', "Før du kan bruge systemet, skal du logge ind")
    }
    res.redirect("/login")
  }
}
// Makes sure that the user has chosen a client to work on
clientChosen = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.selectedClient) {
    next()
  }
  else {
    res.redirect("/chooseClient")
  }
}
```

And I use them like this:

```
app.get("/", loggedIn, clientChosen, cases.home)
```

When I remove the function from my route like this

```
app.get("/", cases.home)
```

The problem goes away, but I do need the functionality of my middleware. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I have edited my question to include my jade configuration and the view in question

Comment: It seems like it may have to do with the way session variables are stored. I'll investigate further

Comment: Can you paste `cases.home()` code. Your other two m/ws look fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I found out that the error is with jade. With the version of jade I use, when i try to `require(./something)`, a non existing variable is refered in the Jade source code. To fix it, i edited out a single line in `./node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:151`

from

```
if (options.client) return new Function('locals', fn)
```

to

```
//if (options.client) return new Function('locals', fn)
```

The line does not seem to be needed at all. Everything works as it should without it. The issue was mentioned at Jade's github page at one time, and I gav ethem the hint. It seemed to be a known problem, that they are dealing with in upcoming version.

For anyone with the same issue, simple comment out that one line, and you're golden

Answer (score 0):

Also, can you `var` before `loggedIn()` and `clientChosen()` routine definitions? Place these definitions before you use them to define `app.get('/');`

```
var loggedIn = function (req, res, next) { // your code };

var clientChosen = function (req, res, next) { // your code };
```

If you don't use it already, can you install (`npm install -g jshint`) and run `jshint <path/to/js-file>`? Does it report any errors?